# How to use Angular observables with CloudFlare workers and fetch?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, cloudflare-workers

I have an Angular9+ PWA (works fine locally). I have deployed it to CloudFlare Workers site. I want to Get some data I have stored in a Worker KV, but do not know how to achieve this. Can anyone advise me?

I have a simple service in the Angular App and I want to call a Get request to retrieve the Worker KV data. I noticed that the Worker file is using 'Fetch' (Promises?) but my Service is using Observables (HttpClient).  So I do not know how to resolve this?

This is the simple service (using async in a component template somewhere):

```
getLocales(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('someUrl');
}
```

This is a test KV:

```
dummyData:  [{id: 1, name: 'test1', desc: 'dummy data 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'test2', desc: 'dummy data 2'}]
```

Not sure what to do next (CloudFlare is new to me).
Thanks.

Comment: So u don't need to worry about it. I think your Angular observable will wait until Worker file promise resolved. Your `getLocales` will be automatically subscribed. It just like Observable(Promise) inside another Observable.

Comment: Thanks for that info, was not aware. Hopefully you are right :) will test it out soon.